# How to access android Resources following removal of package name from Manifest in AGP 8.0+?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-resources

Newer versions of Android Gradle Plugin do not allow for package variable to be declared in the Android Manifest file.

I have therefore removed `package` from Manifest and instead added `namespace` variable to my modules `build.gradle.kts` file. I then realised that i still need access to Resources via the `R` import but this no longer works because i have removed `package` from Manifest.

So how can i access my Resources without declaring `package` variable in manifest?

### Manifest

```xml
<!-- NOTE package variable below has been removed-->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mymoduleame">
```

### Build.Gradle.kts

```kotlin
android {
    namespace = "com.example.mymoduleame"
    ....
}
```

```kotlin
import com.example.mymoduleame.R // Error: Unresolved reference R
```